# registered callback through TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable() but it doesn't get called

Tags: android-ndk, google-project-tango

I tried the new (since tango sdk August 2016 "Tania Borealis") TangoPointCloud interface to get depth frames from our tango Yellowstone tablet.

i did call:

```
TangoConfig_setBool( config, "config_enable_depth", true );
TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable( onDepthFrameAvailable );
```

but this callback is never called:

```
static void onDepthFrameAvailable( void* context, const TangoPointCloud* cloud ) {
  LOGVI( "\nGOOGLE TANGO DEPTH FRAME AVAILABLE" );
}
```

on the other hand, the color camera callback works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call at first

```
TangoConfig_setInt32( config, "config_depth_mode", TANGO_POINTCLOUD_XYZC );
```

even though TANGO_POINTCLOUD_XYZIJ (config_depth_mode == -1) is deprecated according to the documentation, it still seems to be the default value for config_depth_mode